# PhpStorm get stuck when using search everywhere

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm and for a while now I am having an issue with it freezes. I use the search everywhere utility with double shift and start searching for a file. It can take two or three times, and for no reason it seems, it get stuck and I need to restart PhpStorm.

If someone can help, thanks.

Comment: 1) Try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- might help in some situations 2) If you are using 2016.2 version -- try 2016.3 EAP (just to see how it will be there)  3) Other than that -- which such kinds of requests you should contact JetBrains support directly -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home

Comment: invlidate caches didn't work. I am using 2016.1, and for some reason I can't update

Comment: No idea on what you mean by "can't update". If built-in Update does not work for whatever reason -- you just go and download full installation package from PhpStorm website and install it manually -- no issues here -- just do not delete config files when updating/removing old version.